# Adjust text color on different themes

Tags: javascript, c#

I work on maintaining a system that could only be displayed with the white background, and recently we adopted the possibility of the user choosing the dark background.

Some text fields are saved with formatting in the database, so if the color of the formatted text is black the view is compromised.

Is there any way to improve the display of these formatted text with black color on the dark background?

I am looking for some javascript library or asp.net compatible to make the color matching.

Here's an example of how data is saved in the database:

```
<p class="CorpodoTexto">&nbsp;</p>
<p class="CorpodoTexto">Todo e qualquer retrabalho &eacute; desnecess&aacute;rio e causa perda
de tempo, v&ecirc;-se logo ao analisar a palavra. Com foco em evitar o retrabalho e
perda de tempo, foi criada a API . Tendo em sua primeira vers&atilde;o a
finalidade de disponibilizar a lista de produtos cadastrada em nosso ERP, bem
como, a possibilidade de inserir atrav&eacute;s de servi&ccedil;o, pedidos no j&aacute; mencionad<span style="color: #000000;">o
ERP.</span></p>
<p class="CorpodoTexto"><span style="color: #000000;">&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp; Este
documento especifica alguns dos principais requisitos da API .
Sua cria&ccedil;&atilde;o se deu para auxiliar desenvolvedores, fornecendo as informa&ccedil;&otilde;es
necess&aacute;rias para a implementa&ccedil;&atilde;o de uma integra&ccedil;&atilde;o coerente e pr&aacute;tica.</span></p>
<p class="CorpodoTexto"><span style="color: #000000;">&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp; As
demais se&ccedil;&otilde;es apresentam as especifica&ccedil;&otilde;es da API </span>e est&atilde;o organizadas da
seguinte forma:</p>
<p class="CorpodoTexto" style="margin-left: 36pt; text-indent: -18pt;"><!--[if !supportLists]--><span style="font-family: Symbol;">&middot;<span style="font-variant-numeric: normal; font-variant-east-asian: normal; font-stretch: normal; font-size: 7pt; line-height: normal; font-family: 'Times New Roman';">&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;
</span></span><!--[endif]--><strong>Se&ccedil;&atilde;o 2 &ndash;
Classes para a comunica&ccedil;&atilde;o:</strong> Descreve o formato das classes de comunica&ccedil;&atilde;o
bem como as tipagens e obrigatoriedades de seus atributos.</p>
<strong><span style="font-size: 11pt; line-height: 107%; font-family: Calibri, sans-serif;">Se&ccedil;&atilde;o
3 &ndash; Servi&ccedil;os dispon&iacute;veis:</span></strong><span style="font-size: 11pt; line-height: 107%; font-family: Calibri, sans-serif;"> Descreve
os servi&ccedil;os dispon&iacute;veis na vers&atilde;o corrente da API  bem como um
exemplo passo&nbsp;</span><span style="font-size: 11pt; font-family: 'Times New Roman';"></span>
```

Comment: Do you know how the background color change is implemented?

Answer (score 1):

Not the worlds best idea, but you can use important to override the specificity of the inline style.

```js
document.querySelector("button").addEventListener("click", () => {
  document.body.classList.toggle("invert");
});
```

```css
body.invert {
  background-color: black;
}

body.invert p, body.invert span {
  color: #FFF!important;
}
```

```html
<button>toggle</button>

<p class="CorpodoTexto">&nbsp;</p>
<p class="CorpodoTexto">Todo e qualquer retrabalho &eacute; desnecess&aacute;rio e causa perda
de tempo, v&ecirc;-se logo ao analisar a palavra. Com foco em evitar o retrabalho e
perda de tempo, foi criada a API . Tendo em sua primeira vers&atilde;o a
finalidade de disponibilizar a lista de produtos cadastrada em nosso ERP, bem
como, a possibilidade de inserir atrav&eacute;s de servi&ccedil;o, pedidos no j&aacute; mencionad<span style="color: #000000;">o
ERP.</span></p>
<p class="CorpodoTexto"><span style="color: #000000;">&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp; Este
documento especifica alguns dos principais requisitos da API .
Sua cria&ccedil;&atilde;o se deu para auxiliar desenvolvedores, fornecendo as informa&ccedil;&otilde;es
necess&aacute;rias para a implementa&ccedil;&atilde;o de uma integra&ccedil;&atilde;o coerente e pr&aacute;tica.</span></p>
<p class="CorpodoTexto"><span style="color: #000000;">&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp; As
demais se&ccedil;&otilde;es apresentam as especifica&ccedil;&otilde;es da API </span>e est&atilde;o organizadas da
seguinte forma:</p>
<p class="CorpodoTexto" style="margin-left: 36pt; text-indent: -18pt;"><!--[if !supportLists]--><span style="font-family: Symbol;">&middot;<span style="font-variant-numeric: normal; font-variant-east-asian: normal; font-stretch: normal; font-size: 7pt; line-height: normal; font-family: 'Times New Roman';">&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;
</span></span><!--[endif]--><strong>Se&ccedil;&atilde;o 2 &ndash;
Classes para a comunica&ccedil;&atilde;o:</strong> Descreve o formato das classes de comunica&ccedil;&atilde;o
bem como as tipagens e obrigatoriedades de seus atributos.</p>
<strong><span style="font-size: 11pt; line-height: 107%; font-family: Calibri, sans-serif;">Se&ccedil;&atilde;o
3 &ndash; Servi&ccedil;os dispon&iacute;veis:</span></strong><span style="font-size: 11pt; line-height: 107%; font-family: Calibri, sans-serif;"> Descreve
os servi&ccedil;os dispon&iacute;veis na vers&atilde;o corrente da API  bem como um
exemplo passo&nbsp;</span><span style="font-size: 11pt; font-family: 'Times New Roman';"></span>
```

other option is you can use JavaScript on page load to find the color and replace it.

Other option is on the server, look for color: #000000 and replace it

Or there is filter:

```js
document.querySelector("button").addEventListener("click", () => {
  document.body.classList.toggle("invert");
});
```

```css
body {
  background-color: white;
}

body.invert {
  background-color: black;
}

body.invert {
  filter: invert(100%);
}
```

```html
<button>toggle</button>

<p class="CorpodoTexto">&nbsp;</p>
<p class="CorpodoTexto">Todo e qualquer retrabalho &eacute; desnecess&aacute;rio e causa perda
de tempo, v&ecirc;-se logo ao analisar a palavra. Com foco em evitar o retrabalho e
perda de tempo, foi criada a API . Tendo em sua primeira vers&atilde;o a
finalidade de disponibilizar a <span style="color:blue">lista de produtos cadastrada em nosso ERP</span>, bem
como, a possibilidade de inserir atrav&eacute;s de servi&ccedil;o, pedidos no j&aacute; mencionad<span style="color: #000000;">o
ERP.</span></p>
<p class="CorpodoTexto"><span style="color: #000000;">&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp; Este
documento <span style="color:green">especifica alguns dos principais requisitos da API.</span>
Sua cria&ccedil;&atilde;o se deu para auxiliar desenvolvedores, fornecendo as informa&ccedil;&otilde;es
necess&aacute;rias para a implementa&ccedil;&atilde;o de uma integra&ccedil;&atilde;o coerente e pr&aacute;tica.</span></p>
<p class="CorpodoTexto"><span style="color: #000000;">&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp; As
demais se&ccedil;&otilde;es apresentam as especifica&ccedil;&otilde;es da API </span>e est&atilde;o organizadas da
seguinte forma:</p>
<p class="CorpodoTexto" style="margin-left: 36pt; text-indent: -18pt;"><!--[if !supportLists]--><span style="font-family: Symbol;">&middot;<span style="font-variant-numeric: normal; font-variant-east-asian: normal; font-stretch: normal; font-size: 7pt; line-height: normal; font-family: 'Times New Roman';">&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;
</span></span><!--[endif]--><strong>Se&ccedil;&atilde;o 2 &ndash;
Classes para a comunica&ccedil;&atilde;o:</strong> Descreve o formato das classes de comunica&ccedil;&atilde;o
bem como as tipagens e obrigatoriedades de seus atributos.</p>
<strong><span style="font-size: 11pt; line-height: 107%; font-family: Calibri, sans-serif;">Se&ccedil;&atilde;o
3 &ndash; Servi&ccedil;os dispon&iacute;veis:</span></strong><span style="font-size: 11pt; line-height: 107%; font-family: Calibri, sans-serif;"> Descreve
os servi&ccedil;os dispon&iacute;veis na vers&atilde;o corrente da API  bem como um
exemplo passo&nbsp;</span><span style="font-size: 11pt; font-family: 'Times New Roman';"></span>
```

Comment: and for different colors of black and white? like gray (at any intensity), red, blue ...

Comment: No clue what you mean, but add different classes?

Comment: If a color is #000000 on the clear theme I would convert to #ffffff, but what if it is #cccccc or #cc66cc?

Comment: How to choose the best color to replace?

Comment: Man, you need to add that to your original post.... That is a totally different question. lol

Comment: Added filter option, not 100% sure of the browser support for it.

Answer (score 0):

Just create a css class that does what you like and add these class to them.
Note that in order to these styles override the inline css you should make them important. 
As I don't know exactly what you need in your css so just giving an example:

```
.dark_mode
{
    background-color: #333 !imprtant;
    color: #fff !important;
}
```

Now you can apply the class while reading from database (server side), or just add it using javascript in client side.